# Qt5 Is there a way to make QLocalServer listen to abstract unix socket?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, unix, qt5

Is it possible to make a `QLocalServer` object listen to unix abstract socket?
I don't see such possibility mentioned in [qt5 docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalserver.html#listen), there only named pipe is mentioned:

> Usually you would just pass in a name like "foo", but on Unix this could also be a path such as "/tmp/foo" and on Windows this could be a pipe path such as "\.\pipe\foo"

So should I create my own socket and make `QLocalServer` object listen to it?

```
int sockfd = ... // a lot of work
QLocalServer *srv = new QLocalServer(this);
srv->listen(static_cast<qintptr>(&sockfd)); // bad code
```

Just that sounds odd knowing how Qt abstract is and how much possibilities it provides.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you're actually trying to achieve.  What is it you want to do that `QLocalServer` doesn't provide?  Sorry if I've missed something.

Comment: @G.M. I want to make it listen to unix abstract socket instead of a named pipe which is filesystem-entity. Unix abstract socket has nothing related to FS at all, it is a kernel entity only. For more details, try to find this information somewhere else please.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your post.  But, no.  Looking at the `QLocalServer` source it certainly doesn't appear as if any provision has been made for the abstract socket type.  Indeed, searching for "qlocalserver+abstract+socket+unix" shows several bugs filed requesting this functionality as well as [this](https://gitlab.com/pteam/pteam-qtbase/commit/980947122307797e1d8da03f768d8f14a360d20b).

Comment: Just as a side note, without using a manually created socket as you pointed out above, it is not possible (yet). See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-16090.

Answer (score 1):

You may have solved this already but just in case...

The fact that passing a manually set up socket descriptor to [`QLocalServer::listen`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalserver.html#listen-1) fails seemed a bit odd so I looked a bit more closely at the Qt source.  The problem is that the use of `qintptr` as the passed parameter type is rather misleading.  Looking at the code shows that the `qintptr` value is treated as a socket descriptor -- not a pointer to a socket descriptor as the name might suggest.

So, try changing...

```
srv->listen(static_cast<qintptr>(&sockfd));
```

to...

```
srv->listen(sockfd);
```

and see if that fixes the issue.

(Note:  I've written some test code that uses the above fix with an AF_UNIX + SOCK_STREAM socket and it all appears to work as expected.)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, sorry.
I am not sure, but maybe there is a way using QUdpSocket, where the use of sockets is straight and not by piping FS.

The thing is, you can create a Server by processing incoming datagrams with:

```
void Server::initSocket()
{
    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 7755);

    connect(udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
            this, SLOT(readPendingDatagrams()));
}

void Server::readPendingDatagrams()
{
    while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());
        QHostAddress sender;
        quint16 senderPort;

        udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),
                                &sender, &senderPort);

        processTheDatagram(datagram);
    }
}
```

Then you can use datagram information in `processTheDatagram(QByteArray datagram)` to do the action you wanna do.

I hope it helps.